# Intellij console not printing logs while debugging java application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

Platform is Windows and Intellij version is 2017. While debugging a Java application, I am not able to see any logs in console window except the Java command.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085), and a video of the problem.

Comment: Mayb your application is using a logging framework and nothing is sent to `stdout`.